# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after normal block (#63)

Tags: c, matrix

i have to send 2 static matrixes to a function that allocated a dynamic matrix,
multiplies matrix 1 by matrix 2, and returns the address of the new matrix.
note that COMM is common.

i've tried to remove the free_matrix line, it works fine.

```
void main()
{
int mat1[ROW1][COMM]={0},mat2[COMM][COL2]={0};
int** newmat=NULL;
//here i randomize the matrixes
newmat=allocate_dyn_and_mult(mat1,mat2); //newmat is now address 
                          //of allocated dynamic after multiplied matrix.
printf("result:\n");
print_dyn_matrix(newmat,ROW1,COL2);          //prints new mat;
free_matrix(newmat,ROW1); //without this line it works fine.
}



int ** allocate_dyn_and_mult(int mat1[ROW1][COMM],int mat2[COMM][COL2]) 
//return pointer to allocated memory in the size of row1 * col2
{
int i;
int **mat;
mat=(int**)calloc((ROW1),sizeof(int*));
for (i=0;i<COL2;i++)
{
    mat[i]= (int*)calloc((COL2),sizeof(int));
}
    matmult(mat1,mat2,mat); //mat will receive the multiply of mat1,mat2.
    return mat;
}
```

frees the memory

```
void free_matrix (int **c, int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    free (c[i]);
free (c);
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Answer (score 3):

First you allocate memory for `ROW1` pointers with

```
mat=(int**)calloc((ROW1),sizeof(int*));
```

But then the loop uses a different length

```
for (i=0;i<COL2;i++)
{
    mat[i]= (int*)calloc((COL2),sizeof(int));
}
```

Where `mat[i]` will write outside the memory allocated when `ROW1 < COL2`, causing heap corruption. The loop should be

```
for (i=0;i<ROW1;i++)
```